# cupy.var (variance) performance much slower than numpy.var trying to understand why

Tags: python, cupy

I am hoping to move my custom camera video pipeline to use video memory with a combination of numba and cupy and avoid passing data back to the host memory if at all possible. As part of doing this I need to port my sharpness detection routine to use cuda. The easiest way to do this seemed to be to use cupy as essential all I do is compute the variance of a laplace transform of each image. The trouble I am hitting is the cupy variance computation appears to be ~ 8x slower than numpy. This includes the time it takes to copy the device ndarray to the host and perform the variance computation on the cpu using numpy. I am hoping to gain a better understanding of why the variance computation ReductionKernel employed by cupy on the GPU is so much slower. I'll start by including the test I ran below.

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
import cv2
from timeit import default_timer as timer

n_runs = 10
n_warmup = 2
n_tot = n_runs + n_warmup
sizes = (100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000)

# NumPy
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s,s)).astype(np.uint16)
        t_start = timer()
        _ = np.var(x)
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f'NumPy: {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}')
    

# CuPy
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s,s)).astype(np.uint16)
        x_nb = cuda.to_device(x)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_start = timer()
        x_cp = cp.asarray(x_nb)
        _ = cp.var(x_cp)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f'CuPy: {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}')
```

The output of this script is as follows

```
NumPy: 100x100 0.00006 +- 0.00000
NumPy: 500x500 0.00053 +- 0.00008
NumPy: 1000x1000 0.00243 +- 0.00029
NumPy: 2000x2000 0.01073 +- 0.00136
NumPy: 5000x5000 0.07470 +- 0.00264
NumPy: 10000x10000 0.28578 +- 0.00313
...
CuPy: 100x100 0.00026 +- 0.00002
CuPy: 500x500 0.00463 +- 0.00068
CuPy: 1000x1000 0.02308 +- 0.00060
CuPy: 2000x2000 0.07876 +- 0.00172
CuPy: 5000x5000 0.50830 +- 0.02237
CuPy: 10000x10000 1.98131 +- 0.03540
```

I also tried using float16 and float32 instead of uint16 (as it looks like the reduction kernels used by cupy work with floats but it didn't change the disparity in any meaningful way for me).
https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/04bf15706474a5e79ba196e70784a147cad6e26e/cupy/_core/_routines_statistics.pyx#L542

Here are some versions associate with my working environment.

```
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.18.5'
>>> cupy.__version__
'9.6.0'
>>> numba.__version__
'0.53.1'
Python 3.6.9
Driver Version: 470.82.01 
CUDA Version: 11.4
```

Any tips about what might be causing cupy to perform so poorly would be appreciated. Also if there are any things that can be done to improve the performance I'de love to know.
I tried reading about ReductionKernels to understand how to optimize them but it's over my head.
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf

**updated results based on feedback from @myrtlecat**

```
with dtype np.float32
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00017 +- 0.00002
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00041 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00097 +- 0.00003
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.00278 +- 0.00016
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.01381 +- 0.00041
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.04313 +- 0.00355
CuPy: 100x100 0.00013 +- 0.00000
CuPy: 500x500 0.00432 +- 0.00013
CuPy: 1000x1000 0.01713 +- 0.00070
CuPy: 2000x2000 0.06713 +- 0.00079
CuPy: 5000x5000 0.41975 +- 0.00259
CuPy: 10000x10000 1.69374 +- 0.01938
NumPy: 100x100 0.00004 +- 0.00000
NumPy: 500x500 0.00022 +- 0.00001
NumPy: 1000x1000 0.00121 +- 0.00018
NumPy: 2000x2000 0.00530 +- 0.00047
NumPy: 5000x5000 0.03432 +- 0.00179
NumPy: 10000x10000 0.14227 +- 0.00503

with dtype np.uint16
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00018 +- 0.00000
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00124 +- 0.00003
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00430 +- 0.00020
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.01537 +- 0.00008
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.07413 +- 0.00330
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.29842 +- 0.01291
CuPy: 100x100 0.00016 +- 0.00000
CuPy: 500x500 0.00359 +- 0.00053
CuPy: 1000x1000 0.01952 +- 0.00058
CuPy: 2000x2000 0.07719 +- 0.00076
CuPy: 5000x5000 0.48284 +- 0.00169
CuPy: 10000x10000 1.96746 +- 0.04353
NumPy: 100x100 0.00006 +- 0.00002
NumPy: 500x500 0.00053 +- 0.00010
NumPy: 1000x1000 0.00224 +- 0.00016
NumPy: 2000x2000 0.00956 +- 0.00034
NumPy: 5000x5000 0.06818 +- 0.00210
NumPy: 10000x10000 0.27071 +- 0.00747
```

**updated script based on feedback from @myrtlecat**

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

n_runs = 10
n_warmup = 2
n_tot = n_runs + n_warmup
sizes = (100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000)


dtype = np.uint16
# dtype = np.float32


def mean(x):
    while x.size > 1:
        x = x.mean(-1)
    return x


def var(x):
    return mean((x - mean(x)) ** 2)


# CuPy (1 axis at a time)
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        # np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s, s)).astype(dtype)
        x_cp = cp.asarray(x)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_start = timer()
        _ = var(x_cp)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f"CuPy (1 axis at a time): {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}")

# CuPy
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        # np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s, s)).astype(dtype)
        x_cp = cp.asarray(x)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_start = timer()
        _ = cp.var(x_cp)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f"CuPy: {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}")

# NumPy
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        # np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s, s)).astype(dtype)
        t_start = timer()
        _ = np.var(x)
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f"NumPy: {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}")
```

**last updated script and results based on feedback from @myrtlecat where he said that it may be an issue with 2d arrays so I tried using reshape to flatten the arrays before calling "var"**

```
# CuPy (flattened)
for s in sizes:
    t_cp = np.zeros(n_tot)
    for n in range(n_tot):
        # np.random.seed(0)
        x = np.random.randn(*(s, s)).astype(dtype)
        x_cp = cp.asarray(x)
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_start = timer()
        _ = var(x_cp.reshape((s * s,)))
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        t_cp[n] = timer() - t_start
    t_mean, t_std = t_cp[n_warmup:].mean(), t_cp[n_warmup:].std()
    print(f"CuPy (flattened): {s}x{s} {t_mean:.5f} +- {t_std:.5f}")
```

the results

```
for uint16
CuPy (flattened): 100x100 0.00018 +- 0.00006
CuPy (flattened): 500x500 0.00107 +- 0.00002
CuPy (flattened): 1000x1000 0.00414 +- 0.00020
CuPy (flattened): 2000x2000 0.01550 +- 0.00036
CuPy (flattened): 5000x5000 0.10017 +- 0.00525
CuPy (flattened): 10000x10000 0.39470 +- 0.01606
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00026 +- 0.00008
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00104 +- 0.00005
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00368 +- 0.00028
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.01364 +- 0.00055
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.07639 +- 0.00311
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.29405 +- 0.00419

for float32
CuPy (flattened): 100x100 0.00015 +- 0.00007
CuPy (flattened): 500x500 0.00043 +- 0.00001
CuPy (flattened): 1000x1000 0.00159 +- 0.00003
CuPy (flattened): 2000x2000 0.00631 +- 0.00030
CuPy (flattened): 5000x5000 0.03827 +- 0.00135
CuPy (flattened): 10000x10000 0.13173 +- 0.00579
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00020 +- 0.00005
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00030 +- 0.00004
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00077 +- 0.00002
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.00215 +- 0.00002
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.01387 +- 0.00049
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.04099 +- 0.00142
```

So it seems like for both uint16 and float32 the results are faster using the 1 axis at a time technique suggested, rather than flattening the 2d array with reshape. Although the reshape is significantly faster than passing the 2d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a partial hypothesis about the problem (not a full explanation) and a work-around. Perhaps someone can fill in the gaps. I've used a quicker-and-dirtier benchmark, for brevity's sake.

### The work-around: reduce one axis at a time

Cupy is **much** faster when reduction is performed on one axis at a time. In stead of:

`x.sum()`

prefer this:

`x.sum(-1).sum(-1).sum(-1)...`

Note that the results of these computations may differ due to rounding error.

Here are faster `mean` and `var` functions:

```py
def mean(x):
    while x.size > 1:
        x = x.mean(-1)
    return x

def var(x):
    return mean((x - mean(x)) ** 2)
```

### Benchmarks

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
from timeit import timeit

def mean(x):
    while x.size > 1:
        x = x.mean(-1)
    return x

def var(x):
    return mean((x - mean(x)) ** 2)

def benchmark(label, f):
    t = timeit(f, number=10) / 10
    print(f"{label.ljust(25)}{t:0.4f}s")

x = np.random.rand(5000, 5000).astype('f4')
x_cp = cp.array(x)

benchmark("Numpy", lambda: x.var())
benchmark("Cupy", lambda: float(x_cp.var()))
benchmark("Cupy (1 axis at a time)", lambda: float(var(x_cp)))
```

Yielding more than 100x speed-up:

```
Numpy                    0.0469s
Cupy                     0.3805s
Cupy (1 axis at a time)  0.0013s
```

The answers are close but not identical due to rounding:

```
> x.var(), float(x_cp.var()), float(var(x_cp))
(0.08334004, 0.08333975821733475, 0.08334004133939743)
```

### Why is it faster?

CUDA-capable GPUs are generally slower than modern CPUs when operating on a single thread, but they achieve high throughput by performing many identical operations in parallel.

Reduction like `sum` or `var` can be parallelised by:

- dividing the input into chunks
- performing reduction on the chunks in parallel
- performing a second reduction on the results for each chunk

For a sufficiently large input array, if the chunk size is chosen well, this will be close to optimal performance. (Note: for small arrays, or squeeze every last drop of performance, requires more advanced techniques like the slides OP linked to).

### I think it's a bug...

I think that cupy *should* be applying this technique to all reductions (my reading of the cupy code is that it does do this). However, for whatever reason, it does a good job of parallelising reductions over a single axis, but not over an entire array. I doubt that this is intended behaviour, but I am not a dev on cupy and so perhaps it is. The generated CUDA code and parameters used to invoke the reduction kernels are quite buried, so I'm not sure exactly what is happening in each case.

### Updated benchmarks

Result of running the updated benchmark script for `uint16`:

```
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00016 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00029 +- 0.00000
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00070 +- 0.00000
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.00242 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.01410 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.05145 +- 0.00149
CuPy: 100x100 0.00016 +- 0.00000
CuPy: 500x500 0.00316 +- 0.00000
CuPy: 1000x1000 0.01250 +- 0.00001
CuPy: 2000x2000 0.07283 +- 0.00290
CuPy: 5000x5000 0.44025 +- 0.00012
CuPy: 10000x10000 1.76455 +- 0.00190
NumPy: 100x100 0.00004 +- 0.00000
NumPy: 500x500 0.00056 +- 0.00001
NumPy: 1000x1000 0.00201 +- 0.00001
NumPy: 2000x2000 0.01066 +- 0.00005
NumPy: 5000x5000 0.08828 +- 0.00007
NumPy: 10000x10000 0.35403 +- 0.00064
```

so about 7x speed-up over numpy, and and for `float32`:

```
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 100x100 0.00016 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 500x500 0.00018 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 1000x1000 0.00021 +- 0.00000
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 2000x2000 0.00052 +- 0.00000
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 5000x5000 0.00232 +- 0.00001
CuPy (1 axis at a time): 10000x10000 0.00837 +- 0.00002
CuPy: 100x100 0.00015 +- 0.00000
CuPy: 500x500 0.00281 +- 0.00001
CuPy: 1000x1000 0.01657 +- 0.00026
CuPy: 2000x2000 0.06557 +- 0.00003
CuPy: 5000x5000 0.37905 +- 0.00007
CuPy: 10000x10000 1.51899 +- 0.01084
NumPy: 100x100 0.00003 +- 0.00000
NumPy: 500x500 0.00032 +- 0.00000
NumPy: 1000x1000 0.00115 +- 0.00001
NumPy: 2000x2000 0.00581 +- 0.00010
NumPy: 5000x5000 0.04730 +- 0.00009
NumPy: 10000x10000 0.19188 +- 0.00024
```

about 40x speed-up over numpy.

Results will be platform-dependent: for comparison, my CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7940X CPU @ 3.10GHz, and my GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti.

Comment: This is a fantastic reply thanks so much. I have re-run my test script using your suggestion and I am now getting Cupy times comparable to those on the CPU.

Comment: I am unsure why you are getting a result of "0.0013s" is low because you are not 40x faster than NumPy while I am not. for a comparable 5000x5000 array, I thought it might have been my use of uint16, but I tried with float32 as well and I got the same result. I wonder if perhaps it is due to a lack of "cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()" after each "var" operation which means it is actually running all 10 timeit operations at once...

Comment: Here are some additional results to show the gains may be cache
# without synchronize
# Numpy                    0.0369s
# Cupy                     0.4397s
# Cupy (1 axis at a time)  0.0108s
# with 10 different data sets (to illustrate potential cpu/gpu memory caching)
# Numpy                    0.1718s
# Cupy                     0.8308s
# Cupy (1 axis at a time)  0.7038s
# with synchronize at end of var and with 10 different data sets (to eliminate potential gpu memory caching)
# Numpy                    0.1755s
# Cupy                     0.8064s
# Cupy (1 axis at a time)  0.6566s

Comment: I'm going to update the original question with the results of using your approach on my original test. I removed the dependence for numba from the test so it may be easier for you to run it as is to confirm if you are getting different performance on your system. I also confirmed that there is a significant difference i performance if one uses np.float32 vs np.uint8 on larger arrays. It appears the performance gain using our approach is for f32: (40x for 10kx10k, 24x for 2kx2k) and for uint16: (6.6x for 10kx10k, 5.02x for 2kx2k). So vs CPU it for uint16 it is similar and for f32 2-4x faster

Comment: My understanding is that the `float(...)` conversion at the end forces `synchronize()`, but even then it's a bit of a hack. I'll run your updated benchmarks and update my answer so we can compare - it may be just platform differences.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for re-running the benchmarks, seems I need a better video card my 1050 aint gonna cut it any more ;). Thanks again for taking the time to provide your answer!

Comment: I just double checked the specs on the cards and a 1050 can do 1981 gflops while a 1080ti can do 10609 gflops fp32 operations a second. this perfectly matches up with the fact your fp32 appears to be finishing 5.15 times faster :) Thanks again.