# Creating a function for 3D mean using cupy and reduction kernel to apply to cupy's generic filter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cupy

I am trying to use cupy to speed up processing for the scipy generic_filter function. I want the cupy generic_filter function to take a kernel function which calculates the mean of a 3D array. However, if I use the cupy.mean function it returns an error:

`TypeError: bad function type`

As far as I can tell the cupy generic_filter function can't take normal functions and needs a custom-defined kernel (either cupy.ReductionKernel or cupy.RawKernel).

Can anyone help in building a custom kernel for calculating the mean of a 3D array? I can't understand any of the documentation for cupy kernels.

Answer (score 1):

I am no pro, but I have been accelerating my functions with CuPy for a month and faced probably similar issues, so I will share what I have found out:

1. The documentation of CuPy is very minimal and scattered around, I would always read NumPy's equivalent if you have to figure out how single functions work, as they are mainly copied from there, also you will find much more from here as well by accepting NumPy answers.
2. Custom kernels are confusing and not worth it with CuPy (imo), and luckily CuPy has something way more user friendly called @fuse, definitely check that out: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.fuse.html
   It basically allows you to write normal functions and to turn them into kernels without any hustle (as far as I understood; they do work for me). Which takes us to
3. Not all CuPy functions can be used within the user created kernels. Most likely the function you want to use just is not supported within the kernel you are trying to create. For me similar thing happened with cp.argmin() for example.
4. Cupy is quite well optimised so that you wouldn't have to go through the hustle yourself, so I would just stick with normal code when you can't put something into a fuse function. Chances are that the functions are also not supported by Numba etc as you probably need lots of array functions.
5. Performance wise there is an issue in CuPy, so if you have multidimensional arrays it can be 100x faster to compute 1 dimension at a time:
   [cupy.var (variance) performance much slower than numpy.var trying to understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677346/cupy-var-variance-performance-much-slower-than-numpy-var-trying-to-understand)

So my Noob workflow to solve any CuPy script challenge:

1. Find a solution for NumPy
2. Translate it to CuPy. Full list of functions between the two: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/comparison.html
3. Check https://readthedocs.org/projects/cupy/downloads/pdf/stable/ for more about @fuse. It states there that: *"Note: Currently, cupy.fuse() can fuse only simple elementwise and reduction operations. Most other routines (e.g.
   cupy.matmul(), cupy.reshape()) are not supported."*
   So what ever fancy functions you would like to throw in, likely wont work.

I myself tried rewriting the argmin function based on some working examples, but it ended up much slower even as a fuse kernel than the inbuilt cp.argmin() function. So based on my exp I would suggest to stay with the inbuilt functions and use them as you would any other normal function. But if you have multiple dimensions and performance is important, I would aim to do the processing 1 dimension at a time where possible. So e.g.: array.sum(-1).sum(-1).sum(-1) instead of array.sum().

CuPy is very nice and easy way to harness the power of the GPU for NumPy functions even for a noob like me. Well worth using it imo. Check the @fuse and then use inbuilt functions for what you can't put into the fuse and you should be good for almost anything.

For calculating mean of an array CuPy offers the inbuilt function cupy.mean(): https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.mean.html

One thing maybe worth mentioning is that I found out that the computation speed may take a hit when your data amounts grow huge. My core utilisation drops from 97% to 39% at big enough array sizes despite not going over the GPU memory limit. For me it happens at around 6 GB arrays I think. But worth mentioning also that despite knowing this, I can't find better alternatives from Numba etc, as they will not support array functions to the extent I would need them to.

Cheers!